# NSTableView is unresponsive when presented in NSApp.runModal(for:)

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, appkit

I've noticed that depending when I call `NSApp.runModal(for:)`, the table view contained in the presented window is unresponsive: it either doesn't scroll at all, or the content only updates after one or two seconds, presumably after the inertial scrolling has ended.

In the sample code below I call `NSApp.runModal(for:)` in 3 different ways:

1. with a direct call
2. inside the callback to `perform(_:with:afterDelay:)`
3. inside the callback to `DispatchQueue.main.async`.

Only method 2 works. Why?

```
@main
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application
        let window = NSWindow(contentViewController: ViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil))
        
        // 1. doesn't work
        runModal(for: window)
        
        // 2. works
//        perform(#selector(runModal), with: window, afterDelay: 0)

        // 3. doesn't work
//        DispatchQueue.main.async {
//            self.runModal(for: window)
//        }
    }
    
    @objc func runModal(for window: NSWindow) {
        NSApp.runModal(for: window)
    }

}

class ViewController: NSViewController, NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate {
        
    override func loadView() {
        let tableView = NSTableView()
        tableView.addTableColumn(NSTableColumn())
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        let scrollView = NSScrollView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500))
        scrollView.documentView = tableView
        view = scrollView
    }
    func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
        return 100
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, objectValueFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> Any? {
        return "\(row)"
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
        let cell = NSTableCellView()
        cell.addSubview(NSTextField(labelWithString: "\(row)"))
        return cell
    }

}
```